# Node.js async.queue hangs when making http requests with request npm module. Shows a

Tags: node.js, csv, http, request

Request: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

I am having trouble while requesting a huge amount of sites (`10000` at once) with the request module in a queue. It works for say 250 or some more list. However, when I am providing a `csv` of anything close to `300` or more the script it just hangs and the `q.drain` never really fires. 
Code:

```
program.command('sanitizedata <file> <outfile>').description('Sanitize Data').action(( file, outfile ) => {
if(file !== '' && outfile != '') {

var request = require("request");
var parse = require('url-parse');

csv({noheader:false, trim:true})
.fromFile(file)
.on('end_parsed', function(SitesArray) {
  var possibleUrls = [];
  var q = async.queue(function (task, done) {
    var parsed = parse(task.url);

    if(parsed.protocol == '') {
      task.url = 'http://' + task.url;
      task.host = parsed.pathname;
    }

    var options = {
      url: `${task.url}`,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'request',
        'Host': `${task.host}`
      }
    };

    request(options , function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (res.statusCode != 200) return done(res.statusCode);

        done(res);
    });
  }, 5);

  SitesArray.map(function( site, index ) {
    q.push(site, function( result ) {
      if( result.statusCode == 200 ) {
        delete site['host'];
        console.log('\x1b[42m\x1b[37m%s\x1b[0m \x1b[46m\x1b[37m%s\x1b[0m', `Assert Success:${site.url}`, `${index}`);
        possibleUrls.insert( site.index, site );
      } else {
        console.log( '\n\r' + result )
        return false;
      }
    });
  });

  q.drain = function() {
    var csvOutput = toCSV( possibleUrls );
    console.log('draining')
    fs.outputFile(`./data/sanitizedata/${outfile}`, csvOutput, function(err) {
      if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(`The file ${outfile} was saved!`);
      process.exit();
    });
    console.log('all items have been processed');
  }
});
}}
);
```

Somewhere near the last request it shows an `ETIMEDOUT (connection timed out)` error. I have data in csv format..

```
index,url
...
...
9993,supercircusspectacular.com
9994,theleadershipnetwork.com
9995,wizardofozthemusical.com
9996,allnews365.com
9997,blog.vendhq.com
9998,businesspropertynetwork.co.uk
9999,dashboardjunkie.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a `return` in front of `done(res);` in order to handle the error case.

```
request(options , function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (res.statusCode != 200) return done(res.statusCode);

    return done(res);
});
```